# Logging out of an RDP session with some program other than explorer.exe as the shell?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, logout

How do you log out of an RDP session when they are using some program other than explorer.exe as the shell?  Normally I use the start menu to log out of an RDP session, but in this case msaccess.exe is the shell so there is no start menu.

Comment: Aside from, say waiting for it to timeout...

Answer (score 0):

Terminating the shell (i.e., Explorer or something else) doesn't log you out.  Your login session over RDP is more than just your shell.  Try this command in a Command Prompt window on the machine you want to logout from (i.e., the machine you have RDP'ed into):

```
C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe /L
```

It should log you out without shutting down the machine.

Comment: On my local machine right?  Cause I don't want to shut their server down.

Comment: No, on the machine you want to logout from.

Comment: Well I don't have a command prompt window over there...

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc. That will launch Task Manager.  Use the `File` -> `New Task (Run...)` menu item to launch `cmd.exe`.  That will open a Command Prompt.

Comment: Oh ....or I could exit Access :-p :)

Comment: Interesting that terminating Access logs you out but terminating Explorer doesn't.  Windows must treat Explorer differently.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Esc doesn't work over RDP.

Comment: It's probably a feature of Explorer.

Comment: Must be a different exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Exit the program that is set as the shell.

Comment: That turned out to work for him, but exiting Explorer doesn't have the same effect in an RDP session (at least not in Windows 7).  Strange.